# Bash Script Passing Variable with a delimiter

Tags: bash, sed, case

I am very new to bash scripting. I want to create a script that parses a variable that contains dashes and uses each parsed value to pass on to do additional function.

ex:

```
project="Acc-Account-Profile_info"
for i in ($project |sed 's/-/ /g')
do
    case $i in ($project |sed 's/-/ /g')
        echo DeptName = $i
        shift
        ;;
    case $i in ($project |sed 's/-/ /g')
        echo GroupName= = $i
        shift
        ;;
    case $i in ($project |sed 's/-/ /g')
        echo projectName= = $i
        shift
        ;;
    esac
done
```

I want the values to be like:-

```
DeptName = ACC
GroupName = Account
projectName= Profile_info
```

right now I keep getting syntax error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider using a shell syntax checker https://www.shellcheck.net/?

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use `read`?

```sh
project='Acc-Account-Profile_info'
IFS=- read -r DeptName GroupName projectName <<< "$project"
echo "DeptName = $DeptName"
echo "GroupName = $GroupName"
echo "projectName = $projectName"
```

Comment: Maybe add a `-r` flag to `read` so we don't treat backslashes as special? Otherwise, LGTM.

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS='-';set -f;project="Acc-Account-Profile_info"
for i in $project
{
case $i in
Account)
  GroupName=$i
  echo $GroupName;;
Acc) DeptName=$i
   echo $DeptName;;
Profile_info)
  projectName=$i
  echo $projectName;;
esac
}
unset IFS;set +f
```

better use set -- for more input data

Comment: Fixes the issues with globs, though I still don't see how this is a useful interpretation of the OP's intent. If they only run `projectName=$i` if `case $i in Profile_info)` matches, how is this different from just running, say, `[[ $project =~ (-|^)Profile_info($|-) ]] && projectName=Profile_info`? You're not sorting data into fields, but only setting a variable to a constant value should an exact string exist inside the input.